# 1 Item not visible in a Dialog with 3 items, "select_user" is a reserved word?

Tags: android

In a very basic ListActivity I want to show a dialog with 3 options when a line is selected.
Everything works fine except that 1 of my items is not ( never ) visible.

[image]

Here is my Dialog creation :

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    final CharSequence[] itemsf = new CharSequence[]{
        this.getString(R.string.select_user),
        this.getString(R.string.update_user), 
        this.getString(R.string.delete_user) 
    } ;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setItems(itemsf, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if(itemsf[item].equals(AdminUser.this.getString(R.string.delete_user))){
                ...
            }else if(itemsf[item].equals(AdminUser.this.getString(R.string.update_user))){
                ...
            }else if(itemsf[item].equals(AdminUser.this.getString(R.string.select_user))){
                ...
        }
        }});
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Here the strings.xml used :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="delete_user">Suprimir</string>
<string name="update_user">Modificar</string>
<string name="select_user">Seleccionar</string>
...
```

The theme used is :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

This issue is not related with the first item of the dialog, if I change the order of my items definition the item is also not visible.

```
    final CharSequence[] itemsf = new CharSequence[]{
        this.getString(R.string.update_user), 
        this.getString(R.string.select_user),
        this.getString(R.string.delete_user) 
    } ;
```

Produce this:

[image]

I discovered that changing my invisible string's declaration from `<string name="select_user">Seleccionar</string>` to `<string name="use_user">Seleccionar</string>`make it being visible.

Does anyone has an explanation of the fact that a string name "select_user" makes the item being invisible?

Is there a list of reserved words to not use when defining dialog items?

Comment: In which android version are you testing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to recreate this. I have used the same code as your and it's working fine for me.

[image]

I even changed the order of the string

[image]

Comment: Strange, So I am thinking its an device specific issue. What you say?

Comment: Which device did you test this on?

Comment: two devices : a Samsung GALAXY Trend Plus "GT-S758" with android 4.2.2 and a Samsung NOTE "GT-N7000" running android 4.0.4. I face the issue on both devices...

Comment: This couldn't be a device related issue. There's something wrong in your project. Are you doing localization? Do you have multiple string files containing the same key-values?

Comment: I'm not using localization, we have just one "strings.xml". I'm quite confident that nothing is wrong in my project, we have produced a lot of applications (22) using this type of dialog and everything worked fine before discovering this. We are only facing this issue with the string name "select_user" and we have tested it in two different devices... May be it's a "Samsung" issue ? Does somebody can reproduce this on a Samsung device ?

Comment: I also tested it in my Samsung Grand Quatro, its working well.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. Didn't face such kind of issue, but if you didn't find any solution, just try with setting string dynamically.

Like,

```
final CharSequence[] itemsf = new CharSequence[]{
        "Seleccionar",
        this.getString(R.string.update_user), 
        this.getString(R.string.delete_user) 
    } ;
```

And thank you for sharing such kind of issue. This is alternative, not a perfect solution for your query.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT :**

As JoelFernandes told, I also tested your code, And found this output in Samsung Grand Quatro( Android version 4.1.2 ).

First I checked it by setting text to TextView :

[image]

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtlbl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:onClick="DisplayDialog"
        android:text="Click to display dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code :

```
TextView txtlbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtlbl);
        txtlbl.setText(R.string.select_user);
```

And I also test with dialog :

```
public void DisplayDialog(View v) {

        final CharSequence[] itemsf = new CharSequence[] {
                this.getString(R.string.select_user),
                this.getString(R.string.update_user),
                this.getString(R.string.delete_user) };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setItems(itemsf, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (itemsf[item].equals(getString(R.string.delete_user))) {

                } else if (itemsf[item].equals(getString(R.string.update_user))) {

                } else if (itemsf[item].equals(getString(R.string.select_user))) {

                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

And output :

[image]

Now I run project in Emulator which is having same OS version which told, Android 4.0.4, But it seems it display perfectly.

Comment: I already have a solution, using another string than "select_user" to declare my string. I was more looking for an explanation of this behavior. Your solution is not relevant for an application supporting multi-lang...

Comment: @Guillaume I have tested code, its display perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

End of a nonsense history.

It was an "Eclispe" issue:

Removing stuff brick by brick into my project I discoverd that my strings.xml was containing two string :

```
<string name="select_user">Seleccionar</string>
...
<string name="select_user"></string>
```

The strange point if that even with "lint" configured to mark the "DuplicateDefinition" as and "error" my eclipse was not showing any errors and allowed me to clean, build and deploy my project many times.

This strange behavior occurred yesterday, I have rebooted my desktop this morning but it didn't changed nothing about the lint not showing the error.

I had to enter into the lint preferences and modify something in order to force lint to run and detect my error into the strings.xml.

So not a device issue nor a Samsung issue, neither reserved words!

Thanks to all of you to have a look into this...